# How to hook and prevent when router is changing?

Tags: reactjs, validation, react-router, react-hooks

When router is changing:

- I need to verify if input value is valid.
- If it is invalid, I need to show validation in input box but not browser prompt

As you know, there's `Prompt` in react router to show prompt when you need to confirm.

```
  <Prompt
      when={isBlocking}
      message={location =>
        `Are you sure you want to go to ${location.pathname}`
      }
    />
```

But I don't want this message and I need to hook when router is changing.
And I also need to prevent to changing router if the input value is invalid.

Comment: You can add event handlers to the Routers [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history)

Comment: @James Thank you! Could you please provide an example within your own answer?